# MongoDB single node replica set faild on restart azure vm

Tags: mongodb, azure, ubuntu, replicaset

I'm running mongodb single node replica set on azure VM with Linux (ubuntu 20.04).

everything worked fine and i was able to start the replica set following the documentation from mongodb.

today i restarted the VM from the azure portal and the mongodb server seems to refuse getting connections.

I got this log from mongod.log :

```
"c":"CONTROL",  "id":20698,   "ctx":"main","msg":"***** SERVER RESTARTED *****"}
"c":"REPL",     "id":21405,   "ctx":"ReplCoord-0","msg":"Locally stored replica set configuration does not have a valid entry for the current node; waiting for reconfig or remote heartbeat","attr":{"error":{"code":74,"codeName":"NodeNotFound","errmsg":"No host described in new configuration with {version: 2, term: 5} for replica set rs0 maps to this node"},"localConfig":{"_id":"rs0","version":2,"term":5,"protocolVersion":1,"writeConcernMajorityJournalDefault":true,"members":[{"_id":0,"host":"cloud.visual-factories.com:27017","arbiterOnly":false,"buildIndexes":true,"hidden":false,"priority":1.0,"tags":{},"slaveDelay":0,"votes":1}],"settings":{"chainingAllowed":true,"heartbeatIntervalMillis":2000,"heartbeatTimeoutSecs":10,"electionTimeoutMillis":10000,"catchUpTimeoutMillis":-1,"catchUpTakeoverDelayMillis":30000,"getLastErrorModes":{},"getLastErrorDefaults":{"w":1,"wtimeout":0},"replicaSetId":{"$oid":"610b7cd7fb1f746f7ce41e65"}}}}}
"c":"REPL",     "id":21392,   "ctx":"ReplCoord-0","msg":"New replica set config in use","attr":{"config":{"_id":"rs0","version":2,"term":5,"protocolVersion":1,"writeConcernMajorityJournalDefault":true,"members":[{"_id":0,"host":"cloud.visual-factories.com:27017","arbiterOnly":false,"buildIndexes":true,"hidden":false,"priority":1.0,"tags":{},"slaveDelay":0,"votes":1}],"settings":{"chainingAllowed":true,"heartbeatIntervalMillis":2000,"heartbeatTimeoutSecs":10,"electionTimeoutMillis":10000,"catchUpTimeoutMillis":-1,"catchUpTakeoverDelayMillis":30000,"getLastErrorModes":{},"getLastErrorDefaults":{"w":1,"wtimeout":0},"replicaSetId":{"$oid":"610b7cd7fb1f746f7ce41e65"}}}}}
"c":"REPL",     "id":21394,   "ctx":"ReplCoord-0","msg":"This node is not a member of the config"}
"c":"REPL",     "id":21358,   "ctx":"ReplCoord-0","msg":"Replica set state transition","attr":{"newState":"REMOVED","oldState":"STARTUP"}}
"c":"-",        "id":20883,   "ctx":"conn1","msg":"Interrupted operation as its client disconnected","attr":{"opId":2573}}
"c":"NETWORK",  "id":22989,   "ctx":"conn1","msg":"Error sending response to client. Ending connection from remote","attr":{"error":{"code":9001,"codeName":"SocketException","errmsg":"Broken pipe"},"remote":"127.0.0.1:55402","connectionId":1}}
```

this is my replication config :

```
{
        "_id" : "rs0",
        "version" : 2,
        "term" : 2,
        "protocolVersion" : NumberLong(1),
        "writeConcernMajorityJournalDefault" : true,
        "members" : [
                {
                        "_id" : 0,
                        "host" : "cloud.visual-factories.com:27017",
                        "arbiterOnly" : false,
                        "buildIndexes" : true,
                        "hidden" : false,
                        "priority" : 1,
                        "tags" : {

                        },
                        "slaveDelay" : NumberLong(0),
                        "votes" : 1
                }
        ],
        "settings" : {
                "chainingAllowed" : true,
                "heartbeatIntervalMillis" : 2000,
                "heartbeatTimeoutSecs" : 10,
                "electionTimeoutMillis" : 10000,
                "catchUpTimeoutMillis" : -1,
                "catchUpTakeoverDelayMillis" : 30000,
                "getLastErrorModes" : {

                },
                "getLastErrorDefaults" : {
                        "w" : 1,
                        "wtimeout" : 0
                },
                "replicaSetId" : ObjectId("611419575ebb3f4f4ebe44ab")
        }
}
```

and mongod.conf

```
# mongod.conf

# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0


# how the process runs
processManagement:
  timeZoneInfo: /usr/share/zoneinfo

security:
  authorization: enabled
  keyFile: /etc/keyfile.txt

#operationProfiling:

replication:
  replSetName: "rs0"

#sharding:

## Enterprise-Only Options:

#auditLog:

#snmp:
```

any ideas why this is happen ?

Comment: Do you have some DNS record to map `cloud.visual-factories.com` to vm ip? And is it a chance that after restart vm ip has been changed?

Comment: Yes i do have a DNS record for the VM ip and no the vm ip didn't changed